# MKOverlay not appearing until MKMapView is zoomed or moved?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkoverlay, mkmapviewdelegate

So I got an MKCirlce (MKOverlay), and I've added it like this:

```
self.current_location_overlay = MKCircle(center: self.current_location!, radius: 200)
self.mk_map_view.add(self.current_location_overlay!)
```

I've set the map delegate and added this MKMapViewDelegate method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if let overlay = overlay as? MKCircle {
        let circle_renderer = MKCircleRenderer(circle: overlay)
        circle_renderer.fillColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        circle_renderer.setNeedsDisplay()
        return circle_renderer
    } else {
        return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    }
}
```

Tho the overlay is not appearing at start, only after panning or zooming the map it appears.

Seems like others have had this problem, tho no solution on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771562/mkpolyline-only-shown-when-map-is-moved) seems to help.

Dose anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have this problem on iOS 10 or 11? I have the same problem but only on iOS 11 beta 4. Works fine on iOS 10. I'll run more tests and file a radar with Apple if it appears to be a problem with MapKit. The code in the post you linked is old – MKOverlayView is deprecated since iOS 7.

Comment: I am indeed running iOS 11 beta 4, I'll try the beta 5!

Comment: Where did you add your first two lines?

Comment: @ReinierMelian After I got the current location, in a custom method.